# Mysql Udf sys_exec function call to shell script

Tags: mysql

I am Calling a shell script from mysql UDF function sys_exec :

```
 SET cmd = CONCAT('cd /home/enablement;sh execute.sh ', CONCAT('1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1'));
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
SELECT result FROM DUAL;
```

But I am getting an error code 32512 in result which is probably of two different users one for mysql and other for linux (for execute.sh script) , can you please guide me the way how can I be able to make mysql user to access execute.sh file while invoking sys_exec function.

Thanks In Adv

Comment: if that's MYSQL it wont work you need to specify your variables, for example: `SET @cmd:= CONCAT('cd /home/enablement;sh execute.sh ', CONCAT('1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1'));`

Comment: yes varaiable cmd is declared in the procedure , I know the error is becuase of not accessing the file execute.sh , how can I make this  shell script (execute.sh) to be accessiable to mySQL user.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this post is old but maybe it would help someone
You should do this 

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop`

 Because AppArmor limits execution of your UDF function.

Comment: Thank you @user1722669. I have been breaking my head for sometime, as sys_exec was always returning 32512. sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown did help!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't stop apparmor completely, just enable your use case in apparmor's mysqld profile. For example i need to use redis inside mysql.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Then insert this line at the end

```
/usr/bin/redis-cli mr,
```

save the file and reload apparmor

```
sudo service apparmor reload
```